# GCP Instance Metadata not passing scope

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I am trying to mount a GCP storage bucket using gcsfuse and service account authentication. Everything mount OK but i only have read permission, see below;

```
hannel@gcpxxxxxxd1:~$ gcsfuse --dir-mode 777 --file-mode 777 test /testing
Using mount point: /testing
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
File system has been successfully mounted.
hannel@gcpxxxxxxd1:~$ ls /testing/
Huh...
hannel@gcpxxxxxd1:~$ echo "test" | sudo tee -a /testing/test.log
tee: /testing/test.log: Permission denied
```

I have confirm the service account has full Storage Admin permission to write to storage service.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSH3U.png]

I have confirm that the instance metadata service is picking up service account

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCU2W.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCU2W.png]

The only issue i see is that the call for `scopes` from the instance metadata service seems to returning 'weird' information `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`

```
curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/xxxxx-768@xxxx-246521.iam.gserviceaccount.com/scopes -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owLr6.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/owLr6.png]

I really  do not want to use the Key JSON workaround

#### Questions:

Is this a know issue?

Am i doing something wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Go to Google Cloud Console. Select your VM. Near the bottom of the details window, what do you have set for "Cloud API access scopes"? You will want "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" which then means that access is controlled by the Compute Engine service account.

Comment: The default setting for Compute Engine scopes is "Read Only" for Cloud Storage.

Comment: It is set to full by default and managed by IAM when using a custom service account. https://i.imgur.com/e1lRxs0.png

Comment: The default IAM settings for the Compute Engine Default Service Account is "Allow default access". This means many APIs are limited in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing Loop on this.

It is now working with no changes, I believe the issue must have been IAM permission replication. Guess a 15 minutes was time was not long enough, an hours seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Hi Hannel, good work finding the solution! Can you own answer? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @PawelCzuczwara plan on doing that. There is a wait  time to mark you own question as answered.